# SwiftUI: VideoPlayer to display different videos stored locally (back and forward buttons)

Tags: swiftui, video-player

I'm still new to SwiftUI and have run into a problem. I need to use back and forward buttons to make the Video Player go to the previous/next video (stored locally). The following code works for one video only, the one declared into the init(), but I can't manage to change the video by clicking the back and forward buttons.
I'm using an array of String called videoNames to pass all the video names from the previous View.
Also, I'm using a custom Video Player for this and I'm gonna include the relevant parts of the code.

This is my View:

```
struct WorkingOutSessionView: View {

let videoNames: [String]

@State var customPlayer : AVPlayer
@State var isplaying = false
@State var showcontrols = false

init(videoNames: [String]) {
    self.videoNames = videoNames
    self._customPlayer = State(initialValue: AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: videoNames[0], ofType: "mov")!)))
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        CustomVideoPlayer(player: $customPlayer)
            .frame(width: 390, height: 219)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.showcontrols = true
            }
        
        GeometryReader {_ in
            
            // BUTTONS
            HStack {
                
                // BACK BUTTON
                Button(action: {
                    // code
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "lessthan")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                        .foregroundColor((Color(red: 243/255, green: 189/255, blue: 126/255)))
                        .padding()
                })
                
                // FORWARD BUTTON
                Button(action: {
                    // code
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "greaterthan")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                        .foregroundColor((Color(red: 243/255, green: 189/255, blue: 126/255)))
                        .padding()
                })
            }
        }
    }
    .offset(y: 35)
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```

This is my custom Video Player:

```
struct CustomVideoPlayer : UIViewControllerRepresentable {

     @Binding var player: AVPlayer

     func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CustomVideoPlayer>) -> AVPlayerViewController {
      
         let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
         controller.player = player
         controller.showsPlaybackControls = false
         return controller
     }

     func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CustomVideoPlayer>) {
     }    
}
```

I've researched for solutions but couldn't find anything relevant. I've tried to modify my CustomVideoPlayer and not pass a @Binding variable... As well, the init() gave me a lot of headaches as it comes back to errors every time I change something...
Any solution would help guys. I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that you'll need is something to keep track of your position in the video list. I'm using another `@State` variable for this.

Whenever that state variable changes, you'll need to update your player. I'm using the `onChange` modifier near the bottom of the code to do this work.

In your `CustomVideoPlayer`, you need to use `updateUIViewController` to make sure the `player` is up-to-date with the parameter being passed in.

Lastly, there's no need for `AVPlayer` to be a `@Binding`, since it's a class that is passed by reference, not a struct that is passed by value.

```
struct WorkingOutSessionView: View {
    
    let videoNames: [String]
    
    @State private var customPlayer : AVPlayer
    @State private var currentItem = 0
    @State var isplaying = false
    @State var showcontrols = false
    
    init(videoNames: [String]) {
        self.videoNames = videoNames
        self._customPlayer = State(initialValue: AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: videoNames[0], ofType: "mov")!)))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomVideoPlayer(player: customPlayer)
                .frame(width: 390, height: 219)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.showcontrols = true
                }
                .onAppear {
                    self.customPlayer.play()
                }
            
            GeometryReader { _ in
                
                // BUTTONS
                HStack {
                    // BACK BUTTON
                    Button(action: {
                        currentItem = min(currentItem, currentItem - 1)
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "lessthan")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                            .foregroundColor((Color(red: 243/255, green: 189/255, blue: 126/255)))
                            .padding()
                    }
                    
                    // FORWARD BUTTON
                    Button(action: {
                        currentItem = min(videoNames.count - 1, currentItem + 1)
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "greaterthan")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                            .foregroundColor((Color(red: 243/255, green: 189/255, blue: 126/255)))
                            .padding()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .offset(y: 35)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .onChange(of: currentItem) { currentItem in
            print("Going to:",currentItem)
            self.customPlayer.pause()
            self.customPlayer = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: videoNames[currentItem], ofType: "mov")!))
            self.customPlayer.play()
        }
    }
}
    

struct CustomVideoPlayer : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
     var player: AVPlayer

     func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CustomVideoPlayer>) -> AVPlayerViewController {
      
         let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
         controller.player = player
         controller.showsPlaybackControls = false
         return controller
     }

     func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CustomVideoPlayer>) {
        uiViewController.player = player
     }
}
```

If this were my own project, I'd probably continue to do some refactoring -- maybe move some things to a view model, etc. Also, I'd probably avoid initializing an `AVPlayer` in a `View`'s init as I mentioned in my last answer to you on your previous question. It works, but there's definitely a risk you'll end up doing too much heavy lifting if the view hierarchy re-renders.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I've tried it already and it doesn't work 100%. When I click the back/forward button, the currentItem changes as per the print, but the video doesn't. I can hear the video's music changing in the background, but not the video itself. For some reason, the Video Player doesn't display the new video. Would you please look into this matter? I'm trying to get rid of the init as you said, but have no other ideas. Thanks

Comment: Please try edited code. Changed one line that was working for audio but not for video. Regarding init, check my answer on the last question you asked -- I describe using `onAppear`. It would change this answer somewhat, but I've answered this question with the code you started with.

Comment: I really appreciate your time. I've seen the line you changed (m4a for mov), that's how I wrote it straight away thinking it was a typo error. It still doesn't display the new video, just the new audio in the background. My understanding is that the CustomVideoPlayer gets the new video, but cannot display it.

Comment: I have tried to lose the init() as per your answer to my other question and the video completely disappears from my preview/simulator. Also, I don't understand 100% what the whole 'Group' (first item in your other answer's body) does.

Comment: That wasn’t the only thing changed. There’s also an update to updateUIViewController. That’s the important part. If you have questions about the other answer, let’s discuss those on the other page.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I didn't see that change. And yes, you're right, that's the important part. I've changed the updateUIViewController and it's all working. Thank you for sharing your knowledge and helping me !!